# R Commander log window height

Tags: r, r-commander

Where and how do I permanently change my option settings in R commander?
Specifically, I want to change the log window height and the output window height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several features are controlled by run-time options, set via the `options("Rcmdr")` command. These options should be set before the package is loaded (e.g. in appropriate *.Rprofile* or *Rprofile.site* files). See `?Commander`.

To change the log window height and the output window height you can use the following:

```
options(Rcmdr=list(output.height=10, log.height=5))
```

**Update**: this works for me

```
# .Rprofile
.First <- function() {
  options(Rcmdr=list(output.height=10, log.height=5))
  library("Rcmdr")
}
```

Comment: I have the following entry in my
`local({
 options(Rcmdr=list(output.height=15, log.height=24))
})` in my Rprofile.site file. However, nothing happens. I'm using R commander from a menu and it run command is as follows:

Comment: `sh -c 'R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES="$R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES Rcmdr" R "$@"'`

Comment: I got it working. At the top of the Rprofile.site file there was some rubbish that I had accidentally uncommented, which probably meant that my changes weren't being read. Thanks anyway.